# Why is my Azure DevOps build pipeline getting more than just the recent changes?

Tags: azure-devops, build-pipeline

I am wondering why my build pipeline for Azure DevOps is getting practically all the changes instead of just the most recent one?

[image: The previous WI and detected changes]

I only made one change to 1 file, that didn't have an associated work item. This is what the change looks like. As you can see I have only changed one file. So why is it detecting all the changes?

[image]

I thought maybe it was because I didn't have this option enabled.
[image]

But even with that option enabled on a pipeline setup the EXACT same way all the changes are still pulled. Am I missing something subtle here?

Comment: Are you rebasing?

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ No, I am not. Does that affect that?

Comment: Sorry, it was a guess. I'm having a hard time guessing what could possibly happened to your pipeline

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ that's okay. I appreciate you at least offering a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There's an option on the pipeline to automatically link work items that are completed in a run.

You can edit the Pipeline and in the settings, tick **Automatically link work items included in this run**. You can pick * for all branches, or a specific branch.

[image: Setting the automatic link work item option]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you did for your pipeline. Every time you change the files of repos for pipeline and then re-run the pipeline, it lists the changes for each build for the current project. This depends on how many changes you have made to the repo project since the last pipeline.

The below shows:

[image]

**Then**, click into the latest pipeline, and that is true, it will list all changes compared to the previous pipeline.

[image]

Click into it and you could get the detailed every single change.

Comment: I used the classic editor to create the pipeline, and I have a CI trigger that happens everytime a push is done to a stage branch. This was the first time the pipeline had ever been run. Does that have anything to do with it? 
Also, when I go to click on the pipeline run it shows the 172 changes and 24 linked Work Items...